# Джанго:"Cannot create form field"

Tags: python, django

В моём джанго проекте есть два приложения, модель из одного из них подключено ко второму и является полем для ModelForm

Первая модель:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .fields import OrderField
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class Subject(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Вторая модель

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from courses.models import Subject

class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    subject = models.ForeignKey('Subject', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='teacher_subject')
    person = models.ForeignKey(User,
        related_name='teacher', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        initials = self.name + ' ' + self.surname
        return initials
```

Форма:

```
from django import forms
from courses.models import Course
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Teacher

class CourseEnrollForm(forms.Form):
    course = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Course.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.HiddenInput)

class TeacherRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ['name', 'surname', 'subject']
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чём заключается моя ошибка, что её вызывает, а не только то, как её исправить

Код ошибки: "ValueError: Cannot create form field for 'subject' yet, because its related model 'Subject' has not been loaded yet"

Comment: Можете более детальней описать ваш вопрос? Добавьте полный код ошибки и изначальную задау.

Comment: @AndrewHolovko Поправил. Задача в том, чтобы пользователь при создании объекта Teacher необходимо было выбрать предмет, который он преподаёт (Subject)

Comment: Добавьте полный код форм и моделей, с импортами.

Comment: @AndrewHolovko добавил

Comment: Я так понимаю эти модели объявлены в разны приложениях проекта. Для такого объявления надо полный путь передать `subject = models.ForeignKey('courses.Subject' ...`. Либо, раз Вы ее импортировали `rom courses.models import Subject` - попробуйте передать сам обект без ковычек. Еще не понимаю смысла `sys.path.append('../')`. И, возможно, Вы забыли выполнить миграции.

Answer (score 0):

1. Переименуйте, `Subject` в `Subject2` - такой класс уже в моделях есть.
2. Замените в `Teacher` :

```
...
subject = models.ForeignKey('Subject2', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='teacher_subject')
...
```

На

```
from app2.models import Subject2
...
subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='teacher_subject')
...
```

По просту в вашей app не мог найти откуда брать Subject2.

Comment: нужно было просто убрать кавычки вот так:
 ```subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='teacher_subject')```
Мда...

Comment: Знаешь как благодарить автора ответа?

Comment: Вот отвечаешь на вопросы однодневок - а они пропадают, не отблагодарив автора решения.

Comment: Ты не решил мою проблему. Нет решения - нет благодарности

Comment: Ты хоть смотрел что я тебе отправил?

Comment: Нет, специально пропустил из-за вредности, как же ещё

Comment: Мой ответ был для вас полезен?

Comment: Нет, я же сказал, он не решил мою проблему > не был полезен